# Write numbers to a file in lua in binary format

Tags: io, lua, binaryfiles

I have a big array with numbers I would like to write to a file.

But if I do this:

```
local out = io.open("file.bin", "wb")
local i = 4324234
out:write(i)
```

I am just writing the number as a string to the file. How do I write the correct bytes for the number to file. And how can I later read from it.

Comment: You want to write `10000011111101110001010` or `34333234323334`?

Comment: I want to write 10000011111101110001010, but not in string format, I want to write 4 bytes, the size of an integer.

Comment: I don't think Lua has built in support for this. Your best bet would be to add some `C` functions to turn numbers into the appropriate strings.

Comment: But if I have over 100k values it will take a lot of space. And Im in corona so I cant call any c functions directly.

Comment: Related: [Reading/Writing Binary files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17462099/183120)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
function writebytes(f,x)
    local b4=string.char(x%256) x=(x-x%256)/256
    local b3=string.char(x%256) x=(x-x%256)/256
    local b2=string.char(x%256) x=(x-x%256)/256
    local b1=string.char(x%256) x=(x-x%256)/256
    f:write(b1,b2,b3,b4)
end

writebytes(out,i)
```

and also this

```
function bytes(x)
    local b4=x%256  x=(x-x%256)/256
    local b3=x%256  x=(x-x%256)/256
    local b2=x%256  x=(x-x%256)/256
    local b1=x%256  x=(x-x%256)/256
    return string.char(b1,b2,b3,b4)
end

out:write(bytes(0x10203040))
```

These work for 32-bit integers and output the most significant byte first. Adapt as needed.

Comment: would you read four bytes at a time or would you read everything and then later split it up in 4 bytes?

Comment: one more question:), if a read one byte at a time it works, if I read 4 bytes, local bytes = f:read(4) local firstByte = string.byte(bytes), how do I get the rest of the bytes, I cant really divide by 256 because its not a pointer to the first position, just a byte

Comment: @Merni, ask a separate question or edit this one with your efforts for reading.

Comment: Since Lua 5.3 you can use [string.pack](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.pack) to write values in binary.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [lua struct](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/struct) for more fine-grained control over binary conversion.

```
local struct = require('struct')
out:write(struct.pack('i4',0x123432))
```