# Lua true Binary I/O

Tags: lua, binaryfiles

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462099/reading-writing-binary-files) question, and I checked it myself.

I use the following snippet:

```
f = io.open("file.file", "wb")
f:write(1.34)
f:close()
```

This creates the file, into which 1.34 is written. This is same as : 00110001 00101110 00110011 00110100 , that is binary codes for the digit 1, the decinal point, then 3 and finally 4.

However, I would like to have printed 00111111 10101100 11001100 11001101, which is a true float representation. How do I do so?

Comment: Use hexafloats: `f:write(('%.13a'):format(1.34))`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question entirely but you might need something like [lpack](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lpack) (or similar) for this.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff's answer is not valid for lua 5.1, but is valid in lua 5.2. (I have no idea if it is correct.)

Comment: BTW, you can simply store 17 decimal digits of the number `f:write(('%.17g'):format(1.34))` to avoid any rounding errors and receive exactly the same number with `tonumber`.  This works in Lua 5.1

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff and the corresponding read command would be f:read(('%.17g'):format(1.34)) ?

Comment: @Sean - read command would be `local num = f:read'*n'`

Comment: I thumbed you down for using a roundabout way of saying that the string "3.14" was written into the file. You could have said it plainly instead of forcing us to run your code.

Comment: @NiccoloM. I believe it is a good practice, as mentioned in Stackoverflow guidlines,  to give example of the used code. I personally, when seeing the snippet will unambiguously understand, regardless of formulation of the description of problem, what is happening - without running the code. So moderator please assist me, to understand what it is about the "Forcing" mentioned here.

Comment: @Sean: I apologize for being rude. I reverted my unjustified thumb down. Mea culpa. You posted simple code. Then, instead of writing `into which "1.34" is written` or `... the string "1.34" is written`, you wrote `into which 1.34 is written`, which necessitated your explaining the nature of this unspecified 1.34, and caused me to question my own understanding of the code. Since I'm impatient in nature I gave up grokking your "windy" explanation and just run the code. My thumb down was retribution. Again I apologize. Probably all people here would find the fault in me, not in you ;-)

Comment: (Hmmm... the site won't let me revert my thumbdown. It seems the question has to be edited first. Sorry.)

Comment: That is okey. The discussion should serve as a clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to convert it to binary representation, using something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886447/convert-signed-ieee-754-float-to-hexadecimal-representation). This [discussion on serialization of lua numbers](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-03/msg00741.html) may also be useful.